# JavaScript naming convention in .NET shop

Tags: javascript, .net, naming, conventions

I have an issue with a request from the project architect. This person wants me to name all of my properties the same way that .NET does naming conventions.

Should I put up a fight to keep JavaScript as JavaScript, or allow the .NET naming convention to creep up on our JS because we're in a .NET shop?

```
//ALL THE RETURN PROPERTY NAMES SHOULD START WITH A CAPITALIZED LETTER - like     MaxItemsPerPage.
return {
    MaxItemsPerPage: _dataModel.pageSize,
    data: _data,
    searchTerm: _searchTerm,
    filterViewModel: _filterModel,
    dataGridViewModel: _dataModel,
    sortOptions: _sortOptions,
    selectedSortOption: _selectedSortOption,
    selectedSortOrder: _selectedSortOrder,
    sortOrders: _sortOrders,
    loading: _loading,
    update: updateData,
    searchResults: _searchResults,
    pageTitle: _pageTitle,
    showSortOpts: _showSortOpts,
    enableSortOpts: _enableSortOpts,
    disableSortOpts: _disableSortOpts,
    showA: _showAscendingOptions,
    showD: _showDescendingOptions,
    selectedSearchTemplate: _selectedSearchTemplate,
    searchListTemplateOptions: _searchListTemplates
};
```

Comment: this might be better on programmers.stackexchange.com.  I voted to close as it doesn't fit here, as it can't be answered objectively.

Answer (score 3):

Javascript code should follow Javascript conventions, including naming conventions.

If you try to write Javascript like you would write C# or VB code you'll just end up with bad Javascript. Writing good code means writing good *idiomatic* code for each language you use.

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I prefer camel case in pure JavaScript code and pascal case for pure-C# properties.

But when you serialize a C# class out to JavaScript via JSON, or model bind posted values that started out as JavaScript objects, the boundaries blur. It's a perfectly valid concern for an architect to say "we should do one or the other consistently." Which way to go depends on many things. When objects cross the bounaries and you have to choose, ask yourself:

Do external parties depend on your published contracts/JavaScript objects, or is it purely internal?

Is JavaScript used for light jQuery behaviors or for significant business concerns? Do you unit test your JavaScript?

Do you use the serialized classes a lot in C#? Throughout many business layers, or unit tests?

For objects that exist on both ends of a C#/JS contract, what % code is in C# and what % is in JS?

Comment: +1 great point about the boundaries blurring